# Find rank and nullity of this linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know how to do questions like this:

[image]

But this one is throwing me off a bit.

> For the linear transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $T(x, y, z) = (x − 2y + z, 2x + y + z)$:
>   (a) Find the rank of $T$.
>   (b) Without finding the kernel of $T$, use the rank-nullity theorem to find the nullity of $T$

Is this right?

I think the equations represent this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

It's a 3x2 matrix which means it represents a transformation from $R^3$ to $R^2$

rank T:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 5 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{5} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{5} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{5} \end{bmatrix}

rank is 2
nullity is 1.

Conceptually did I do this right? The equations that I'm given represent equations that I can then convert into a coefficient matrix which I can use to determine the missing variables right?

Comment: You don’t need to do all that work. The two rows of the matrix are obviously linearly independent, so its rank is 2.

Comment: Why is it so obvious?

Comment: When you only have two vectors, they are linearly dependent iff one is a scalar multiple of the other—they’re on the same line, which is what linear dependence means in its most basic form.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, the matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & -2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
is the matrix associated to $T$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. Without doing reduction, the rank of $T$ is given by the rank of one of the biggest submatrices with non-vanishing determinant. In your case there is a submatrix of rank $2$ with determinant non-zero (as gimusi is showing), so the rank of $T$ is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your way is correct, as an alternative since

$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1  \end{bmatrix}\neq 0$$

we can conclude that $\operatorname{rank}=2$ and then nullity is $3-2=1$.